# After redirect back to a form page, the old form values are still displayed on Inertia.js on Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs

I am trying to make the system like this:

1. Displays a first form page. After a user submit the form, redirects to the second form page.
2. Displays the second form page. When a user click a delete button on the page, redirects to the first form page.

However, when I click the delete button in 2, the old form values are still displaying on the first form page. I tried following methods:

1. preserveState:false on submit.

```
Inertia.post(props.deleteDraftUrl, null, {
                    preserveState: false
                });
```

this works for when I click a delete button on the first page, but when I click the one in the second page, the old form values are still displayed.

2. use preserveState:false of the form made by useForm.

```
form.post(props.deleteDraftUrl, {
                    preserveState: false
                });
```

This doesn't work too.

3. onSuccess: () => form.reset();

```
Inertia.post(props.deleteDraftUrl, null, {
                    preserveState: false,
                    onSuccess: () => form.reset(),
                });
```

This doesn't work too.

I have been stacked on this problem for a day. Any suggestions are helpful.

Updates: Added the entire code in the script of the component. The first page and the second page are pretty much the same. I also simplified and modified the code mostly for the security reasons.

```
import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import {Inertia} from "@inertiajs/inertia";

export default {
    props: {
        pageTitle: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        defaultValues: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    remember: ["form"],
    setup(props) {
        const form = useForm({
            value1: props.defaultValues.value1,
            value2: props.defaultValues.value2,
            value3: props.defaultValues.value3,
        });

        
        const deleteDraft = () => {
            if (confirm("delete the draft?")) {
                Inertia.post(props.deleteDraftUrl, null, {
                    preserveState: false,
                    onSuccess: () => console.log('success!'),
                });
            }
        };
        

        return {
            form,
            pageTitle,
            deleteDraft,
        };
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you add a `console.log('On success');` in your `onSuccess` callback, do you see it after you click the delete button?

Comment: Thanx for the response. Yes, it displays.

Comment: Can you update your question to add the code of your component? :)

Comment: Remove form.reset() in onSuccess callback

Comment: @Garry Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried it, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Your controller?

Comment: Which controller do you want? The one of the submit url? (The redirect response is returned in the type of Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse.)

Comment: You are setting the initial values of the form to `props.defaultValues`. Therefore, when it resets the form, it's setting it back to what you had initially in `props.defaultValues`.

Comment: I understand your idea and do you know how to achieve that? I experimentally have added form.reset() just after defining form variable in the first page component, but this does not work.

Comment: form.defaults() is also not working. It seems to be undefined method.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You are passing the default values of your fields when initializing your form:

```js
const form = useForm({
    value1: props.defaultValues.value1,
    value2: props.defaultValues.value2,
    value3: props.defaultValues.value3,
});
```

So when you reset the form, it will reset to those values.

### Solution

You can update the defaults of your form before resetting.

```js
Inertia.post(props.deleteDraftUrl, {
    onSuccess: () => {
        form.defaults({
            value1: null,
            value2: null,
            value3: null,
        });

        form.reset();
    },
});
```

If you have a lot of fields to reset, you can loop through the defaultValues to clear them.

```js
Object.keys(form.data()).forEach(field => form.defaults(field, null));

form.reset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not still working. Weirdly, though I use useForm to make the form constant without making it reactive as stated in the inertia documentation (https://inertiajs.com/forms), form.defaults() seems to be undefined method and gets following error :  'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: form.defaults is not a function' , but form.reset exists.

Comment: @spaceofsn Which version of Inertia are you using? You can see in the link you've provided that the `defaults` method should exist.

Comment: According to the package.json: "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.10.0",   "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3": "^0.5.1". I rerun composer install and npm run watch, then I rechecked importing useForm like this : 'import {useForm} from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3"'.

Comment: @spaceofsn Composer is used for updating the server side adapter of Inertia. You need to update the client side adapter, which is handled in npm. So try running `npm update @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue3` instead of `composer install`. I'm running on `@inertiajs/inertia-vue3: ^0.6.0` and the `defaults` method is available. :)

Comment: it seems 'preserveState : false' in the second page only controls the second page's form, and it does not affect to the first page's form.... Weirdly, form.reset()  does not even reset the form though the documentation says it resets the form.  I checked it changing redirect url after the submission to the second page from the first page.

Comment: Oh, i could not see the comment. I will try that 'npm update @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue3'

Comment: I found the problem and the answer. I sincerely appreciate your dedication and cooperation.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @spaceofsn What was the problem and the answer?

Comment: Just another guy wrote a code which changes defaultValues in the SERVERSIDE. Really sorry for the stupid cause, but your suggestion really helped to find out the cause.

Comment: @spaceofsn Oh I see! No problem, glad you figured it out. :) Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and the answer. For some reasons, just another guy wrote a code that keeps the inputted values in the defaultValues variable at the first page's CONTROLLER! That's why it never clears form.

So the answer is : Making the process which keeps the inputted values in the defaultValues variable not working after submitting a deleting-draft form.

Sorry for the stupid cause, and "preserveState : false" seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

onSuccess: () => this.form.reset();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).